# Is it possible to list all Facebook markets during a posting?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-marketplace

The Facebook Marketplace has made numerous updates over the course of a year. 
I remember that a year ago I could do an advertisement and see all the markets where I could publish it (after registering for the group-markets). Now it is no longer so, and I see only a part of the markets to which I am subscribed.
Perhaps it is impossible (unless there is a new Facebook update) but I would like to know if there was a way to list all the markets to which I am subscribed, to try to increase the visibility of my items.